# Dex errors when compiling android_tutorial_pubsub

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to compile android_tutorial_pubsub before, but something has changed recently and I get these weird dex exceptions from a fresh build:

```
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/xmlrpc/metadata/XmlRpcSystemImpl$1$1;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:95)
```

I'm not sure what they mean.  There's about 16 of them.  Any ideas?

I've done ./gradlew install on rosjava_core and I set the targets for android_gingerbread and android_tutorial_pubsub before running ../gradlew debug in the android_tutorial_pubsub directory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31252/dex-errors-when-compiling-android_tutorial_pubsub/) by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I updated my Android SDK Tools to r17 and that seems to have fixed things....

---

Originally posted by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) with karma: 93 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0